# findDuplicate number in golang using hashmap

Tags: go

hi i want ask about findDuplicate in golang

if in python i can do this

```
def findDuplicate(data):
  seen = []
  for number in data:
    if number in seen:
      print(number)
    seen.append(number)
   
  print(seen)
data = [1,2,4,5,6,4]
findDuplicate(data)
#expected output 4
```

is there any similiar function in golang like "if number in seen" on python?
Thank you

Comment: Create a value of the `map[int]struct{}` type and check if a key exists there (assuming your `number` is an integer).

Comment: Please mention your usecase, sample inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through your data and write to a [map](https://blog.golang.org/maps) if it is not a duplicate. And append to duplicates slice if it is already exist in the map. Sample code is like below.

*Note: if you have multiple duplicates with same value, this code is showing all multiple duplicates. If you need to see same duplicate value once, this should be changed*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []int{1,2,4,5,6,4}
    findDuplicates(data)
}

func findDuplicates(data []int)  {
    values := make(map[int]struct{})
    var duplicates []int
    for _, d := range data {
        if _, ok := values[d]; ok {
            duplicates = append(duplicates, d)
            continue
        }

        values[d] = struct{}{}
    }

    fmt.Println(duplicates) // Output: [4]
}
```

run with [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GkQxJY-cn_8)

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [maps](https://blog.golang.org/maps)

Example usage:

```golang
func findDuplicate(data []int) {
    uniq := map[int]bool{}
    for _, i := range data {
        if uniq[i] {
            fmt.Printf("found duplicate %v", i)
        }
        uniq[i] = true
    }
}
```